# AT&T Assembly Syntax in C program (GCC compiler)?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I have the following program (AT&T Assembly Syntax) that works perfectly on its own if I compile it with GCC compiler on Windows x86:

```
LC0:
    .ascii "Hello, world!\0"
.globl  _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Can this simple program be executed in a C program? I tried with the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    __asm__ ("LC0:\n\t"
             ".ascii 'Welcome Message\0'\n\t"
             "LC1:\n\t"
             ".ascii 'Hello\0'\n\t"
             "_main:\n\t"
             "LFB11:\n\t"
             "leal  4(%esp), %ecx\n\t"
             "andl  $-16, %esp\n\t"
             "pushl -4(%ecx)\n\t"
             "pushl %ebp\n\t"
             "movl  %esp, %ebp\n\t"
             "pushl %ecx\n\t"
             "subl  $20, %esp\n\t"
             "call  ___main\n\t"
             "movl  $1, 12(%esp)\n\t"
             "movl  $LC0, 8(%esp)\n\t"
             "movl  $LC1, 4(%esp)\n\t"
             "movl  $0, (%esp)\n\t"
             "call  _MessageBoxA@16\n\t"
             "subl  $16, %esp\n\t"
             "movl  $0, %eax\n\t"
             "movl  -4(%ebp), %ecx\n\t"
             "leave\n\t"
             "leal  -4(%ecx), %esp\n\t"
             "ret\n\t");


    return 0;

}
```

I get one error:

*Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `8'*

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude GCC does not have an inline assembler.  GCC does text replacement on your inline assembly and pastes it into its own assembly output.  That said, clang does have an inline assembler which doesn't understand some constructs.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve] because your code doesn't even include the character `8` that your error message is complaining about.  How exactly did your run a compiler on the file containing the `__asm__` statement at global scope?  And why bother putting asm at global scope instead of a separate `.s` file?

Comment: The embedded `'\0'` could cause problems. You might want to try and escape it like `"\\0"`. Or use the `.asciiz` directive instead.

Comment: Junk at the end of the line means there is ... junk at the end of the line. Check for hidden or meaningless characters at ... the end of the line.

Comment: And *why* do you want even do something like that? What is the purpose of copy some assembly directly into a C function? Why can't you keep the assembly file as it is and use it instead of wrapping the code in a C function?

Comment: Some programmer dude: This is purely experimental and useless, read about it somewhere and just wanted to try it out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine:

```
__asm__(
"LC0:\n"
"    .ascii \"Hello, world!\\0\"\n"
".globl  _main\n"
"_main:\n"
"    pushl   %ebp\n"
"    movl    %esp, %ebp\n"
"    andl    $-16, %esp\n"
"    subl    $16, %esp\n"
"    call    ___main\n"
"    movl    $LC0, (%esp)\n"
"    call    _puts\n"
"    movl    $0, %eax\n"
"    leave\n"
"    ret\n"
);
```

Simply C-string-literal-escaped the double quoted string and `'s/^/"/;s/$/\\n"/'` elsewhere.

My gcc's assembler doesn't accept single quoted string literals as in

```
LC0:
    .ascii 'Hello, world!\0'
.globl  _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

so I don't see why it should start accepting them if you supply them through `__asm__`.

Comment: I tried the first example, received error - "symbol `_main' is already defined". Did it work for you on your computer?

Comment: @Lavonen Did you add any other code when compiling this? Such as, a definition of a `main` function?  Because that's of course not going to work.  Put the `asm` statement outside of any function.

Comment: @Lavonen: you probably put that *inside* a C definition of a `main` function like in your question.  That's incorrect, and not what PSkocik is doing.  Put the asm at global scope, or use `__attribute__((naked))` if you want to write the function prologue and the `ret` yourself.  Looking at the C compiler's asm output from source that contains inline asm is useful when debugging inline asm (especially with constraints, but also in this case.)

Comment: BTW, the normal way to make zero-terminated strings is with `.asciz` aka `.asciiz`, rather than putting a `\0` inside the quoted string.

Comment: Now it works, I had the code inside a function. Didn't understand it has to be outside for whatever reason. Thank you for an awesome answer, will vote it up!))

Comment: Levonen if changing single quotes to escaped double quotes is your definition of awesome, you should raise your standards, but thanks. :D I'm glad I could help. :)